# After A New Role Is Added

Tags: jwt

In a single page application, a POST request along with a JWT in the header is sent to a server. In the happy path, a new role will be added to the user after a new data is created on the server. Say the original body data is the following:

```
{
  "sub": "jane",
  "auth": "ROLE_USER",
  "exp": 1506916072  // Sun Oct 01 2017 20:47:52 GMT-0700 (PDT)
}
```

And a new data shall be

```
{
  "sub": "joe",
  "auth": "ROLE_BLOGGER,ROLE_USER",
  "exp": <a new time>
}
```

How shall the client obtain another JWT with the new data? It wouldn't be reasonable to ask the user sign in the application again. The user login data could be saved in the client local storage to solve this problem. That, however, isn't a good practice.

Comment: Assuming you gave the user a refresh token along with the access token when they logged in, they should be able to exchange that refresh token for a new access token with the additional role.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have looked at refresh token. It requests an auth server. We don't use any auth server.